# Problems configuring JSF 2.0 on Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, web-applications, jsf-2, eclipse-indigo, mojarra

I'm developing a web application with JSF 2.0 on the IDE Eclipse Indigo (the last version).

But on *Project ->Properties -> Project Facets*, the option *JavaServer Faces* is configured on version 1.2 and when I try to change the version to 2.0, an error message apears

> Cannot change version of project facet JavaServer Faces to 2.0.

Strangely, the JSF libaries in my project are all the 2.0 version.

I think this is the problem that is causing my pages not to show simple xhtml tags like `<h:outputLabel>` and `<h:inputText>`.

The JSF libraries that I'm using was obtained on the Mojarra project 2.0.6

Hope someone could help me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an Eclipse quirk. See also [Eclipse bug 201792](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=201792) which is never been fixed.

The only way to change the JSF Facet version is by editing the following line of the `/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml` file

```xml
<installed facet="jst.jsf" version="1.2"/>
```

to

```xml
<installed facet="jst.jsf" version="2.0"/>
```

Other than that, you can also just ignore it altogether. Changing the version of that facet really doesn't do any new magic for you anyway. The final WAR build still contains the JSF 2.0 libs and if you have redeclared `<faces-config>` root declaration of  `/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml` file to comply JSF 2.0, then there should be no problems. If you still encounter problems with using Facelets (XHTML files, as you say yourself), then you should ask a new and more specific question about that here.

Comment: Reading your lines I wonder why Eclipse does not offer JSF2 support. JSF2 is not that new.

Comment: @Alex: Eclipse definitely supports JSF2 (since Helios SR2). This particular one is just a bug which makes developer unable to change JSF project facet version from 1.2 to 2.0 in an existing JSF 1.2 project. Creating a new JSF 2.0 project from the beginning on is not a problem.