# JSF2.2 in eclipse on wildfly8.1

Tags: eclipse, maven, jsf-2

I have a project created from some maven archetype, dont remmebrer realy which one. I use maven and Eclipse Kepler.

The project is deployed on Wildfly8.1 server

In the project facests I have JSF 2.0 and when I try to change the facet to JSF 2.2 I get the massege "Cann not change version of facet JavaServerFaces ..."

Do I have to change something in my maven pom file?

Here is my maven pom :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <parent>
      <artifactId>ypay</artifactId>
      <groupId>si.arctur</groupId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </parent>

   <artifactId>ypay-web</artifactId>
   <packaging>war</packaging>

   <name>ypay Web module</name>

   <dependencies>

         <dependency>
     <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
     <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
     <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>  
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>  
            <version>4.0</version>  
        </dependency>   

      <!-- Dependency on the EJB module so we can use it's services if needed -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>si.arctur</groupId>
         <artifactId>ypay-ejb</artifactId>
         <type>ejb</type>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Import the JAX-RS API, we use provided scope as the API is included 
         in JBoss AS 7 -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
         <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included 
         in JBoss AS 7 -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
         <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Import the JPA API, we use provided scope as the API is included 
         in JBoss AS 7 -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

       <!-- Import the JSF API, we use provided scope as the API is included 
         in JBoss AS 7 -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
         <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
         <version>2.2.4</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.16</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>       

       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
               <!-- Java EE 6 doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to catch 
                  up! -->
               <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate or similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171862/problems-configuring-jsf-2-0-on-eclipse-indigo

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which Eclipse plugins you use. Assuming you have a current version of JBoss Tools, the facets should be set correctly when first importing the Maven project into Eclipse, depending on the POM dependencies.

In your POM, there's a mixture of Java EE 6 and 7 dependencies, which might be causing the problem.

Try deleting the `javax:javaee-api:6.0` dependency - you have indidual Java EE 7 APIs further down in your POM -, then run **Maven | Update project** in Eclipse.

If that does not help, delete the project from the workspace, delete all Eclipse metadata from the file system (`.project, .classpath,. settings`) and re-import the project.